# First Pontryagin class on real Grassmannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

I wonder if real Grassmannian manifold $SO(p+q)/SO(p) \times SO(q)$ have nontrivial first Pontryagin class? I only have physics background and know really little about characteristic class theory.

Comment: @studiosus thanks for the answer, but it seems that only $SO(p+2)/SO(p) \times SO(2)$'s Pontryagin classes are discussed. Actually the triviality of $p_1$ is very important in physics consideration. Can I ask further except for case $q=1$, any other real Grassmannian has trivial $p_1$, and what about that of the classifying space $BO(q)$? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a partial answer:

1. If $p=1$ or $q=1$ then this manifold is the $n$-sphere which, therefore, has zero Pontryagin classes.
2. If $p=2$ or $q=2$, then this manifold always has $p_1\ne 0$. This follows from the formula 9 on page 525 of this paper by Borel and Hirzebruch:

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/bh1.pdf

In principle, the paper gives a recipe for computing $p_k$ for all oriented Grassmannians (and other compact homogeneous spaces), but I did not do the more general calculation.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it seems that only $SO(p+2)/SO(p) \times SO(2)$'s Pontryagin classes are discussed. Actually the triviality of $p_1$ is very important in physics consideration. Can I ask further except for case $q=1$, any other real Grassmannian has trivial $p_1$, and what about that of the classifying space $BO(q)$? Many thanks! @studiosus

Comment: If $p=q=2$, then $SO(4)/SO(2)\times SO(2) = SU(2)\times SU(2)/ U(1)\times U(1) = S^2\times S^2$, so has $p_1 = 0$.  It's been awhile since I've looked at Borel-Hirzebruch, and I don't immediately how to get the result from formula 9.

Comment: I just looked at the B-H paper in more detail and I think it shows $p_1(SO(p+2)/SO(p)\times SO(2)) \neq 0$ except when $p=2$ ;-).  More generally, one has $p_1(SO(p+2)/SO(p)\times SO(2)) = ((p+2) - 4) g$ for $p\geq 2$, so is non zero so long as $p\neq 2$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: You are right, I was a bit careless with my computation and missed the 4d case, thanks for the correction!